# Swift exclamation mark before a text

Tags: swift, button, uinavigationbar, option-type, uibarbuttonitem

This tutorial I am currently working on says I have to disable the Save Button until the text field has some value in it.
Here is the code:

```
saveButton.isEnabled = !text.isEmpty
```

Does the exclamation mark before text.isEmpty mean that the save button is enabled is the text is not empty same way that != mean not equal to?
I know exclamation mark means force unwrap, but I thought you put the exclamation mark after the text.
BTW(I have tested it and it works as the tutorial says so)

Comment: yes it works as a negation of the Bool value. Btw you can also use textField.hasText to check if the field is not empty

Comment: Please read [Swift Language Guide : Logical Operators](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID76)

Comment: This is equivalent of saying `text.isEmpty == false`

Answer (score 2):

The exclamation mark before `text.isEmpty` called [*Logical NOT*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID76) operator, it inverts the  boolean value.

```
saveButton.isEnabled = !text.isEmpty
```

means that if `text` is empty, the `saveButton` will *not* be enabled, and vice versa.

To make it more clear, if we tried to translate it as an if-statement, it should be as:

```
if text.isEmpty {
    saveButton.isEnabled = false
} else {
   saveButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The exclamation mark is both a postfix operator (and as you said is the the force unwrap operator used this way) and a prefix operator. The latter is the boolean negation, so when `text` is the empty string, `text.isEmpty` is true and negating it with an exclamation mark before gives `!text.isEmpty` which is false, disabling the save button.